# Avoiding loops, condition column based on id column

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, apply

My goal is to determine the number of successful trees in a plot (id) using their height. Successful trees are those that are 85% the height of the height of their biggest neighbor (neighbor_ht) In each plot, all trees have their species observed (species) and height estimated from their diameter (est_height) but there is always 1 tree where the height is directly observed (dom_species, dom_ht).

```
#Create Example data set

id<-c(rep(1,3),rep(2,7))
species<- 
c("oak","maple","oak","maple","maple","apple","oak","maple","maple","maple")
est_ht<-c(11,24.5,32.3,6.5,7.8,23.4,23.4,32.3,33.5,33.5)
dom_species<-c(rep("oak",3),rep("maple",7))
dom_ht<-c(rep(32,3),rep(45,7))
neighbor_ht<-c(rep(34,3),rep(46,7))

df<-data.frame(id,species,est_ht,dom_species,dom_ht,neighbor_ht)

#calculate success

df$success<-ifelse(est_ht>=(0.85*neighbor_ht),1,0)
df

    id species  est_ht  dom_species dom_ht   neighbor_ht success
1   1     oak   11.0         oak     32          34       0
2   1   maple   24.5         oak     32          34       0
3   1     oak   32.3         oak     32          34       1
4   2   maple    6.5       maple     45          46       0
5   2   maple    7.8       maple     45          46       0
6   2   apple   23.4       maple     45          46       0
7   2     oak   23.4       maple     45          46       0
8   2   maple   32.3       maple     45          46       0
9   2   maple   33.5       maple     45          46       0
10  2   maple   33.5       maple     45          46       0
```

In plot 2, there should be 1 maple success, but the estimated height was too low. I'd like to add 1 success to a plot in a row where "species" matches "dom_species" and when the observed "dom_ht" is taller than the "est_ht", however this should only be done for the tallest "est_ht" and only once in the case of ties. The resulting data frame like should look like the one below. Note that a success has been added to the last row for one of the maples in id = 2, "success_2" = 1

```
df$success_2<-c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1)
df

 id species est_ht dom_species dom_ht neighbor_ht success success_2
1     oak   11.0         oak     32          34       0         0
1   maple   24.5         oak     32          34       0         0
1     oak   32.3         oak     32          34       1         1
2   maple    6.5       maple     45          46       0         0
2   maple    7.8       maple     45          46       0         0
2   apple   23.4       maple     45          46       0         0
2     oak   23.4       maple     45          46       0         0
2   maple   32.3       maple     45          46       0         0
2   maple   33.5       maple     45          46       0         0
2   maple   33.5       maple     45          46       0         1
```

I've failed at multiple for loop attempts, and a few using the apply function. I haven't posted them here to keep things simple. I have a feeling there is an elegant solution to the problem which does not have to use a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The following reproduces your expected output. There should be more elegant ways of achieving the same, this seems oddly complex given your problem statement.

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    group_by(dom_species) %>%
    arrange(dom_ht) %>%
    mutate(
        success = ifelse(est_ht >= 0.85 * neighbor_ht, 1, 0),
        success_2 = case_when(
            est_ht >= 0.85 * neighbor_ht ~ 1,
            species == dom_species & dom_ht > est_ht & est_ht == max(est_ht) ~ 1,
            TRUE ~ 0),
        success_2 = success_2 - lead(success_2, default = 0),
        success_2 = ifelse(success_2 < 0, 0, success_2))
## A tibble: 10 x 9
## Groups:   dom_species [2]
#      id species est_ht dom_species dom_ht neighbor_ht   success success_2
#   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>        <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1    1. oak      11.0  oak            32.         34.        0.        0.
# 2    1. maple    24.5  oak            32.         34.        0.        0.
# 3    1. oak      32.3  oak            32.         34.        1.        1.
# 4    2. maple     6.50 maple          45.         46.        0.        0.
# 5    2. maple     7.80 maple          45.         46.        0.        0.
# 6    2. apple    23.4  maple          45.         46.        0.        0.
# 7    2. oak      23.4  maple          45.         46.        0.        0.
# 8    2. maple    32.3  maple          45.         46.        0.        0.
# 9    2. maple    33.5  maple          45.         46.        0.        1.
#10    2. maple    33.5  maple          45.         46.        0.        0.
```

Explanation: The `ifelse` and `case_when` parts implement the logic rules as laid out in your post. We use `lead` to deal with "ties" in `est_ht == max(est_ht)`, and keep only the last entry.